# How to dynamically change meta tag description for blog/:id in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, meta-tags

I created a blog website with reactjs, I want to implement a dynamic meta tag so that when user share each link on any social media platform, the meta tag description for each blog will show up.

I saw this tutorial and I implement this in my project, but The meta tags are not showing.

https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/

Here is my route:

```js
import React from "react"
import './App.css';
import Home from "./pages/home/home";
// import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Auth from "./pages/Auth/Auth";
import Singlepost from "./pages/home/singlepost";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <Navbar /> */}
    <Routes>  
        <Route exact path ='/' caseSensitive={false} element={<Home/>}  />
        <Route  path='/auth' caseSensitive={false} element={<Auth />}/>
        <Route  path='/:topic' caseSensitive={false} element={<Singlepost />} />   
    </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my server below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios')
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs"); 
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const indexPath  = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html');

// static resources should just be served as they are
app.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    { maxAge: '30d' },
));
// here we serve the index.html page
app.get('/*', async(req, res, next) => {
    fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during file reading', err);
            return res.status(404).end()
        }
        // get post info
        const postId = req.query.topic;
        const post = axios.get('https://inspiredformen.herokuapp.com/posts', postId);
        console.log("post", post)
        //  getPostById(postId);
        if(!post) return res.status(404).send("Post not found");

        // inject meta tags
        htmlData = htmlData.replace(
            "<title>React App</title>",
            `<title>${post.topic}</title>`
        )
        .replace('__META_OG_TITLE__', post.topic)
        .replace('__META_OG_DESCRIPTION__', post.topic)
        .replace('__META_DESCRIPTION__', post.topic)
        // .replace('__META_OG_IMAGE__', post.thumbnail)
        return res.send(htmlData);
    });
});

// listening...
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Error during app startup', error);
    }
    console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});
```

Here is index.html file:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>__META_OG_TITLE__</title>

    <meta name="description" content="__META_DESCRIPTION__"/>
    <meta name="og:title" content="__META_OG_TITLE__"/>
    <meta name="og:description" content="__META_OG_DESCRIPTION__"/>
   
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
   
   ...
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Please, I will appreciate if anyone can help me with to solve this problem.
Thanks all